# use html to get image and create link from database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, url

I have a column in my database that stores images that are links, when i populate them in a gridview on my asp.net page I want it to display the image as a link but when i did it i just get the text below.

```
   <a href="http://www.url.com/url/url/url/url.html"><img src="http://www.url.com/url/url/url/url.jpg"></a>
```

My goal is to have a list of the images and when a user clicks the image they will go to another page. This is a start of my page, and i was attempting to use a gridview but now I am not sure what to do

Comment: If at all possible, it might be much better to simply save the URL of the image - but not the HTML encoding of the image as a link. Sometimes what you have is what you're stuck with though, so just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: you dont think there is a way?

Comment: "what you have is what you're stuck with"...What's to stop you from cleaning your database by writing a script that replaces the markup with just the URL?

Comment: i dont mind cleaning up my database as i only have a couple test rows, but i just don't know how to turn my markup into what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Are you saying that the HTML that you're saving in the database is being rendered as text instead of as HTML?

Comment: yes alison, that is my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't save markup

Instead just save a URL. In your case two of them since one points to `*.html` and the other to `*.jpg`. Or just without extensions if they're always the same except for the extensions. This way you can easily change your markup later and still use the same data from the DB.

But apart from this fact of not saving non-data in DB you could at least provide some relevant code you're using. We'd much easier tell you where you're doing it wrong.

### Using GridView

The problem you're having are column templates. Check [this link](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-vb) out and see how you can customize the display of a particular column in a GridView. Essentially you will have to provide your own template and do whatever you please with your DB data.

Comment: this is what i am saving <a href="http://www.url.com/url/url/url/url.html"><img src="http://www.url.com/url/url/url/url.jpg"></a>

Comment: if i save url.com/url/url/url.html and url.com/url/url/url.jpg in seperate columns how could i change it into a single link on my page to create a list of the images/links

Comment: yeah sorry, im just not sure how i would turn the urls into just a list of images that are links

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: I've added some additional info to my answer. Check it out. The thing is that `DataGrid` HTML encodes any data it outputs to make it safer for XSS attacks.

Comment: nice i got the image to display now i just dont now how to make the img a link. the way i did it is by adding an img box to the template field and setting the bind to the url of my img that is stored in my db

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: *img box*? What do you mean by that? You've probably added an `IMG` element or `asp:Image`. You can as well add an anchor element `A` or `asp:LinkButton` to create a link as well.

Comment: ahh dont worry i got it just needed to work more in the client side